# How do I launch the VBA Editor?

Tags: c#, vba

I am building some software, and it will run VBA Script.  I want to allow my users to use a VBA Editor.  How can I do this?

Comment: This link looks like it has the information you are looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Is your software an add-in to one of the Microsoft Office applications?

Comment: Assuming you want custom scripting capabilities you could alternatively use VBScript, JavaScript (JScript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean you want to add VBA to your own app, and show the user a nice VBA editor as well - so totally not Office related?

If so, then VBA must be licensed from Microsoft; e.g. AutoCAD also does it.  Maybe a license also includes some extra's like an editor component?

EDIT

Too bad; according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications#Development) and [Summit software](http://summsoft.com/vba/) Microsoft stopped handing out VBA licenses to new customers in 2007...

Comment: Yeah the VBA SDK used to ship with a nice activex/component version of the standalone VBA editor itself which you could automate, import your own namespaces etc.. Shame they killed it off.